# How to find a texture for a background image for website?

Tags: website-design, background, images, texture, patterns

I am looking for a texture pattern for an image that is similar to the one Path.com uses:

```
 https://www.path.com/images/about/bg.gif
```

I want a similar image pattern so i can use it as a background for my website. It will be helpful if i can find a way to create it too.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking for a list of sites where you can download any kind of texture backgrounds? Or are you asking us to find you a background texture like the one you posted? The first question can be answered by googling "background textures" or going to any stock art site. The second isn't appropriate for this site.

Comment: Link is dead...though the 404 page is pretty amazing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a resource gathering question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[www.cgtextures.com](http://www.cgtextures.com) has tons of free textures, and many of them are already tiled for you, and in a variety of sizes.

Answer (score 5):

have a look at this online tool:
http://bgpatterns.com/

Comment: other nifty tools (though not strictly related to your request) are:  
http://www.stripegenerator.com/  
http://www.pixelknete.de/dotter/

Answer (score 1):

Just adding my 2 cent. I have found google images very useful and handy. Sometimes just by typing  "wood pattern" in google images gives me lots of free resources.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider [Subtle Patterns](http://subtlepatterns.com/).  It has a cool widget that allows you to cycle through their gallery of designs in realtime on the document you are working on.  Find it [here](http://bradjasper.com/subtle-patterns-bookmarklet/#.UT0nEFc9-gw).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few helpful tutorials that show how to create this "Linen" texture using PhotoShop:

http://www.elixirgraphics.com/index.php/entries/blog_creating_an_ios_linen_texture_in_photoshop

http://nclud.com/sketchbook/ios-fabric-texture-tutorial/

(I am not associated with any of these websites).

Hope these tuts help out. They certainly were very valuable to me.